# How to screen capure part of a window on keypresses?

Tags: windows, screen-capture

How can I capture part of screen, on a Windows 10 PC, when any key is pressed (could be a specific key) or on mouse-motion, such that each such captured image is stored automatically as a JPEG/PNG file with suffix that is an auto-incremented?

Comment: Yes there are several such tools, and they are easily google-able.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic on SuperUser.  However, you can ask questions like this at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).